# Android Studio - Calculator Not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I used the exact code and instructions from this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7eIS8dQKTc, to add a calculator into one of the activities of an application I am creating for college. However, whenever I go to press any of the buttons, I just get, 'Unfortunately (my app name here) has stopped working'.

If my code is necessary to provide, I (think?) I have uploaded it here, this is the entire app so far.
https://github.com/soc0t/College-Apllication-Testing

Comment: There must be a some error that gets printed. Paste that here.

Comment: Look at the logcat (stack trace)

Comment: Here is the Logcat when I press one of the buttons with 'OnClick', bare in mind it also crashes on those with 'OnAdd', and 'OnCalculate'. 
http://puu.sh/o5j4d/af87ab8c71.png

Answer (score 1):

NullPointerException on EditText.setText() often means your findViewById failed to find the control.

Calculator.java

```
    EditText edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    edit.setText(total);
```

res/layout/activity_calculator.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3" />
```

they need to match.